# Spring 4 mvc: trigger an event when the web application is ready

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, events, listener

I have a Spring 4 mvc application and I would like to make a GET request to another node.js service when the web application is available.

The client is build with React.js and served by Spring.

I already tried the following Spring Listeners:

- ServletContextListener
- ApplicationListener
- ContextLoaderListener

The node application when receives the call takes a screenshot of the homepage. The result is a white page because the event fires too soon.

I suppose that the problem could be the react js bundle taking more time to load.

Is there a away to solve this? Maybe I miss the right Listener.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is for spring boot not simply spring-web.

You need the `ApplicationReadyEvent` as documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners

If your spring boot app is defined as follows, here's a possible implementation:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(YourMainClass.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void EventListenerExecute(){
        System.out.println("App is ready for requests");   
    }
}
```